# Add plural forms for synonym votes range strings

Tags: bug, tag-synonyms, localization, plurals, transifex

Tooltip for tag synonym vote count can contains two different strings:

- key: `ea140cb5f7b850c2ee1df44c9c7395c2`

  > total votes (when a synonym gets a score of $ScoreRequiredToApprove$ it is automatically approved)
- key: `8c16926e660e10dd8178a9416cf44124`

  > total votes (when a synonym gets a score of $ScoreRequiredToDecline$ it is automatically declined)

These stringZ don't have plural forms in Transifex.

Comment: Your "string" doesn't have a plural form either :)

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog done :)